# Exit shell from a subshell

Tags: shell

I believe I am calling exit in a subshell that causes my program to continue:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep str file | while read line
do
        exit 0
done
echo "String that should not really show up!"
```

Any idea how I can get out of the main program?

Comment: Are you saying `String that should not really show up!` gets printed?

Comment: @MiserableVariable I just tested; it does get printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trivially restructure to avoid the subshell -- or, rather, to run the `grep` inside the subshell rather than the `while read` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
  exit 1
done < <(grep str file)
```

Note that `<()` is bash-only syntax, and does not work with `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can check the return code of the spawned subshell to see whether the main main should continue or not.

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep str file | while read line
do
        exit 1
done

if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi

echo "String that should not really show up!"
```

Will not print the message because the subshell exited with code `1`.

Comment: how about `done || exit` instead of the four unnecessary lines to exit the current shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can "exit" your shell by sending a signal to it form your subshell:replace `exit 0` with `kill -1 $PPID`

But i don't recommend this approach.I suggest your subshell to return a special meaning value,like `exit 1`

```
#!/bin/bash
grep str file | while read line
do
        exit 1
done
exit 0
```

then your can check your subshell's return value by $?

like `subshell.sh ;if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then exit 1 ;fi`

or simply `subshell.sh || exit`

Comment: That doesn't work -- the `exit 1` causes the pipeline subshell to exit, but not the outer shell, which continues on to `exit 0`.

Comment: When subshell return 1,outer shell will execute `exit`.

Comment: I don't get it.did I misunderstand?

Comment: the "outer shell" is the one that's running `grep str file`; the subshell is the one running `while read line`. Your answer assumes that there's a different, completely separate shell script somewhere -- this isn't the case; rather, the subshell is being implicitly created by the pipeline.

Comment: When I run it by zsh,the shell will exit(the echo won't execute).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to avoid a subshell in the first place. The (currently) [accepted reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13318252/15809) shows such a solution but it will only work in Bash or Bash compatible shells:

> Note that <() is bash-only syntax, and does not work with /bin/sh.

Here's one that will work in any POSIX conforming shell:

```
newline=$( printf '\n_' ); newline=${newline%_}; readonly newline

set -f
IFS=$newline

for line in $( grep str file )
do
    # ...
done

set +f
unset IFS
```

The two important things to make the code safe are:

1. Ensuring that `IFS` is set to line break. Only then a for-loop will just process full lines. By default it would process every word of every line. Unsetting `IFS` at the send resets it back to default.
2. Disabling globbing (`set -f`). By default all values of a for-loop are first expanded with globbing before being assigned to the loop variable. E.g. if your file contains a line like `a*`, then the shell will first try to find files in the current working directory matching that pattern and if it finds any, it will assign every found file to `line`, one after another, and never set  to `a*`. Only if no such file is found, `line` is really set to `a*`. `set +f` re-enables globbing again after the loop.

And in case anyone wonders, yes, getting a newline character in a POSIX conforming way is really tricky. `"\n"` does not expand to newline in POSIX strings ([See here](https://onecompiler.com/bash/3zyk2vtd8)). And `$'\n'` is a bash extension again, not POSIX.

When using `printf`, `\n` does expand to newline, however you cannot capture that newline as when capturing command output, all trailing newlines are stripped from the captured output, so `newline="$( printf '\n' )"` results in an empty string. That's why I'm printing `"\n_"`, so the newline is not a trailing one and then remove the `_` of the captured string, which will in fact result in a string containing only a newline character.